# Mysql fetch array, table results 2

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I've recently posted a similar question but that was to create one row of cells across and after it reaches 3 columns, it creates a new row, so I can have 3 columns of infinite rows. That was solved.

Now what I need is this (GIVEN A and B should be records from the database using `$row = mysql_fetch_array($results)` so basically it would be something like `$row['username'];` for A and B ).

```
  <tr>
  <td><img src="images/ava/A.png" /></td>
  <td>A</td>
  <td width="2px" rowspan="3"></td>
  <td><img src="images/ava/B.png" /></td>
  <td>B</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
  <td><div class="gauge"><div class="innergauge"></div>A</div></td>
  <td><div class="gauge"><div class="innergauge"></div>B</div></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
  <td>A</td>
  <td>B</td>
  </tr>
```

As what you can see, the record I got from my database has to fill in to this format, where A is one record and B is another, then if there is record C, this whole thing should repeat again to form a second row.

Answer (score 0):

Build each section as you go, combine them at the end. Here's how you do sections 1 and 3, the middle section is left as an exercise:

```
$section1 = '<tr>';
$section2 = // start $section2
$section3 = '<tr>';
$i = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array(...)){
    if($i > 0){
        // won't happen the first time through the loop
        $section1.= '<td width="2px" rowspan="3"></td>';
    }
    $section1 .= '<td><img src="images/ava/'.$row['username'].'"/></td>';
    $section1 .= '<td>'.$row['username'].'</td>';

    // now do $section2

    $section3 .= '<td>'.$row['username'].'</td>';

    $i++;
}
$section1 .= '</tr>';
// finish $section 2
$section3 .= '</tr>';

// now output
echo $section1 . $section2 . $section3;
```